# Quasi concavity and quasi convexity of a max function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, special-functions

Consider the production function: Q = max {K, L}. We have to find out whether this function is quasi concave or quasi convex.

According to me, since this function is concave, it should automatically be quasi concave (also the upper contour sets are convex). And It is quasi convex because the lower contour sets are convex.

However my answer book states that these are only quasi convex and NOT quasi concave. I dont understand why?

Comment: Any assumptions on $K$ and $L$?

Comment: No. Nothing is mentioned.

Comment: Without any assumptions on $K,L$ it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: what assumptions would be required?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the function for, e.g., the special case $K=0$? Does this univariate function look convex or concave to you

Comment: I think the concept that you got wrong is that the function is concave, intermediate micro tells us that the max{K,L} production is concave. But it is a concave LEVEL curve, this doesn't guarantee that the function would be concave or convex in the three dimensions!. The primary condition for an interior optima is that the function should be quasiconcave, since the max function does not give us an interior optimum, we can say the function is quasiconvex.